# Connect remote rabbitmq cluster using rabbiqmq cli or management tool

Tags: rabbitmq

How can I connect to a remote cluster/queue using a rabbit cli and management plugin with or without docker?

I need to create vhost. I couldn’t find how to set the host in docker or cli.
If there are no ways to connect, can I use some Node.js package to create vhost?

Answer (score 1):

Can you not log in to the management console? Usually runs on port 15672 - see [here](https://www.rabbitmq.com/management.html#usage-ui).
Can also hit the management console HTTP API directly to do things like creating a vhost - see [here](https://pulse.mozilla.org/api/) e.g.

```
curl -i -u guest:guest -H "content-type:application/json" \
   -XPUT http://{hostname}:15672/api/vhosts/foo
```

Comment: It’s not enabled

Comment: Can you SSH to the host (and exec into the container if it's running in docker) and use the cli e.g. `rabbitmqctl add_vhost foo` as per https://www.rabbitmq.com/vhosts.html#creating